# C# Linq filter and sum datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable (see the image)

[image]

I am trying to sum '1. rate' in the 'Event' column for each clientID.

I'm using the code below to do so:

```
  var group = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("Client Id"));
  foreach (var g in group)
  {
      int sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("Client Id") == g.Key
      & r.Field<string>("Total Units") == "1. rate").Count();
      Console.WriteLine(sum);
  }
```

As you might notice in the image, many of the 'UnitID's' are the same. I'm trying to apply a filter so for example. If any of the same 'UnitID' has a 'Event' of 'Refundering' I want to filter all those 'UnitID's', and not just the single row. Any ideas how I can apply this filter are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that in the linq Total Units is = Event in the mysql

Comment: Replace the "Where" with another "GroupBy"

Comment: That does not work

Comment: Can you please post your datatable as a snippet rather than an image?

Comment: Your code shows `Count` and not `Sum`, and looks at "Total Units", a field we don't have for "1. rate", and "1. rate" is a value that can't be summed. Please make your description match your code, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Group by `UnitID` and remove the groups that contain "Refundering", then ungroup keeping only the "1. rate" rows, group by `ClientID` and count the results.

```
var ans = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("UnitID"))
            .Where(rg => rg.All(r => r.Field<string>("Event") != "Refundering"))
            .SelectMany(rg => rg.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Event") == "1. rate"))
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("ClientID"))
            .Select(rg => new { ClientID = rg.Key, CountRate = rg.Count() });
```